# Overlapping graphics

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, canvas

I am trying to develop an admin dashboard with site metrics and I have menues showing different data when you click on them. I write the front-end on Backbone.js and use Jquery to reduce the number of calls. The problem is that when I browse the page and when I open a new graphic and mouse-over it, sometimes it starts to overlap with the previous graphics. What can I do so that I only see the graphic relevant to the option I select?

```
newAndTotalUsersPerMonth: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#User').hide();
            $('#right').hide();
            $('#left').hide();
            $('#third').hide();
            $('#logLabel').hide();
            $('#main-view').addClass('small-2');
            $('#main-view').append('<p id="label"></p>');
            var $label = $('#label');
            var text = $label.text();
            $label.text(text.replace(text, "New and total users per month"));
            $('#main-view').append('<div id="container" class="row">'+
            '<col-md-12>'+
            '<div id="canvasArea">'+
            '<canvas id="nu1" style="width:960px; height:250px; overflow:hidden;"></canvas>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</col-md-12>'+
            '</div>');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/analytics',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    var labels = [];
                    var dataSet1 = [];
                    var dataSet2 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        labels.push(data[i][1] + "." + data[i][0]);
                        dataSet1.push(data[i][2]);
                        dataSet2.push(data[i][3]);
                    }
                    var lineData = {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "New Users",
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: dataSet1

                            },
                            {
                                label: "Total Users",
                                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                data: dataSet2
                            }

                        ]
                    };
                    if(!$('#canvasArea').is(':empty')) {
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("nu1").getContext("2d");
                        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, {
                            responsive: false
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#nu1').reset();
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("nu1").getContext("2d");
                        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, {
                            responsive: false
                        })
                    };
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: nothing shown would give anyone else any indication of layout to help solve an overlap problem

Comment: can you create a fiddle